# Worklow 2013 does not stop

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, workflow-manager

I'm working on SharePoint Server 2016. Some monts ago I developed a 2013 Workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013. Today I noticed many Workflow instances are on status `Started` even they completed their job, so I decided to stop them manually from the UI (`http://mySharePoint/_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx?List={ListGuid}&WorkflowInstanceName=WFGuid`). They don't stop.

Maybe buggy UI? ...I decided to wrote a powershell script:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$sourceWebURL = "http://mySharePoint"
$sourceListName = [Guid]"ListGuid"
$web = get-spweb $sourceWebURL
$list = $web.Lists[$sourceListName]

$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($web)
$sub = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
$wfs = $sub.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($list.ID)
$wfis = $wfm.GetWorkflowInstanceService()

$item = $list.GetItemById($itemId)

$workflowInstances=$wfis.EnumerateInstancesForListItem($list.ID,$item.ID)

foreach($wf in $workflowInstances) 
{
    $wfis.CancelWorkflow($wf)
}
```

They don't stop either...

This is the scenario:
[image]
Each running WF is on `Started`, has done what it had to, but is not stoppable.

Somebody has an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following PowerShell commands to cancel all workflow instances on the list.

```
$sourceWebURL = 'your site'
$sourceListName = 'your list'
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
$items = $spSourceList.getItems()

#-- Getting a Workflow manager object to work with.
$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($spSourceweb)

$wfis=$wfm.GetWorkflowInstanceService()

Foreach($item in $items){
    $wfinstances =  $wfis.EnumerateInstancesForListItem($spSourcelist.ID, $item.ID);
    foreach($instance in $wfInstances)
    {
             $wfis.CancelWorkflow($instance);             

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me the differences to my code?